# WebSphere 8 Application Server Configuration Issue

Tags: java, jndi, websphere-8

**Issue:**

Our Java appliation is deployed on WebSphere 8 application server and we have reports module as part of our application. There is a report which runs for about 30 minutes (there is a Stored Procedure call which takes time) but on one of the environments after 15 minutes the browser shows "The page can't be displayed" but the request is still active in the server and completes successfully without any errors in WAS/App logs.

So, I have tried to replicate the issue in other environment by manually adding wait in DB procedure and the same issue has occured after 60 minutes.

Based ont he above analysis, I suspect this is somthing related to the configuration. I have explored the WAS server properties and searched enough but I have not found any solution aroud the issue mentioned.

Any resolution around this issue would be of great help.

Comment: Probably not the best solution to do it in one request. Can't you just initiate the report and fetch it later in another request when ready.

Comment: Maybe you are going through IHS? Then check the params in the plugin-cfg.xml file regarding response timeout. But as Henry suggested you should redesign your app, as nobody will wait 15 min waiting for response.